# Google Cloud's Transfer Service for on-premises data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

I need to copy data files from a Linux server to Google Cloud Storage buckets and schedule this process to run hourly. I think the "Transfer for on-premises" is the most suitable option for this process. However, I am struggling to find detailed information how to implement this process step-by-step. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/on-prem-overview#how_does_it_work) details this process:

> 1. Install [Docker](https://docker.com/) and run a small piece of software, called an [agent](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/key-terms#agents), in
>      your private data center. The agent runs within a Docker container and
>      has access to your locally mounted NFS data.
>
>    See [Installing and running the on-premises agent](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/managing-on-prem-agents#install-agent) for more information.
> 2. Start a Transfer Service for on-premises data transfer from the Google
>      Cloud Console. You'll provide the NFS directory and a destination
>      Cloud Storage bucket to transfer data to.
>
>    See [Creating a transfer](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/managing-on-prem-jobs#create-transfer) job for more information.
> 3. When the transfer starts, it recursively traverses through the given
>      NFS directory and moves data it finds to your Cloud Storage bucket.
>
>    Transferred data is checksummed, files with errors are re-tried, and
>      data is sent via a secure connection. A record of the transfer's
>      progress is written to log objects within your destination Cloud
>      Storage bucket. You can track the progress of the transfer within the
>      Google Cloud Console.
> 4. When the transfer completes, you can view error samples within the
>      Google Cloud Console. You can also review the transfer log for a
>      catalog of files transferred and any errors.

Regardless, just by going to the **Transfer Service for on-premises data Web Console** [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/transfers/on-premises), you are guided through once you click on **Create Transfer Job**.